# How to get Current System Process id in crystal report?

Tags: sql-server, windows, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, spid

I want to add some sql query conditions into crystal report.

I add the a formula field SPID, and make the sql query as
`{ONE_TABLE.ONE_COLUMN_SPID} = {@SPID}`

However, how to make the field SPID show the current system process id?
or is there a function in crystal report to get current system process id?
OR is there a way to put the argument @@SPID into the crystal report? (Ps, @@SPID is the way in Sql Server to get SPID)

```
SELECT　* FROM ONE_TABLE WHERE ONE_COLUMN_SPID = @@SPID
```

Thanks. I really need your help.

Comment: I have found a solution.

Comment: Just put the value into this field in the program. No more answer is needed. Thank you very much.